# Cannot do the Selection of the subject that have been selected in Career Clusters Interest Survey form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project for Career Clusters Interest Survey, but I'm stack on the Select query.

I have a database which looks like below:

[image]

I want to SELECT only three of "studies" where the visitor has selected.

The idea is for Cluster Interest Survey: newfuturescareernavigator.org/assessment/step-1/

This is the manual how the fields are selected: 
http://www.careertech.org/sites/default/files/StudentInterestSurvey-English.pdf

Comment: what did you try so far code-wise ?

Comment: Hi, I don't have idea how to start this selection. Here you have the logic: http://www.careertech.org/sites/default/files/StudentInterestSurvey-English.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This is the idea how to make a query:

```
SELECT s.name, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM `group`, studiesgroup 
   WHERE studiesgroup.group_id IN (4,3,7,6,11) 
   AND `group`.id = studiesgroup.group_id 
   AND s.id = studiesgroup.studies_id) AS GroupTaken 
FROM studies s
ORDER BY `GroupTaken` DESC
```